# Visual studio MVC3 Strongly typed Views shows everything

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-3

I have this really strange problem. When I try to create a strongly typed view, I get really alot of classes that have nothing to do with the project. I tried to clean the solution and rebuild.

here is a screenshot:

[image: all classes in strongly typed view]

Comment: Normally I would only get the models from the model map, to create a strongly typed view from them.

Comment: Have you installed the recently-released MVC 3 Tools Update? It improves the type filtering in this dialog.

Comment: I installed the update, it fixed a part of the classes. But not all of them...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wonder why people worry so much about IDE support in such situations. It is well known that ASP.NET MVC is a new technology and IDE support is, how to put it gently, far from ideal. I mean, is it really so annoying to you? Can't you just copy-paste the namespace and class name of the view model in this textbox? I am sure Microsoft will do better job in future releases of the framework to improve tooling support in Visual Studio (even if personally I really don't give a damn as I never rely on tooling support).

I know I am not answering your question and I apologize for this. But, come on, it's not the end of the world. Let's focus on solving some real world application problems and move on.

Comment: I don't have the heart to upvote this non-answer, but happen to agree completely.

Comment: I know, but I thought it was just a setting or a mistype.. If it is not fixed yet. No rpoblem :)

Comment: @Vince2doom, I doubt it is an error from your part. IDE support in views sucks a bit. Once you get accustomed to it you might even no longer pay attention. It's what I end up doing and enjoy the power of the framework itself :-)

Comment: This doesn't answer the users question.  If you want to rant, do so in a comment.